# UITableView imageView reuse other cell's image

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I need to make a `UITableView` with different numbers of images posted in it, something like `Facebook` or `Twitter` or `WeChat` friends. return dynamic cell height and arrange images depends on the number of them.

It should looks like this [image: sample image 1]

And I do the dynamic cell height for image as:

in `HomeTableViewCell.m`

Make the height auto layout constraint of view which contains post images as property

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *height;
```

and set the constant of it to different value to make cell dynamic height

```
self.height.constant = imageArray.count > 3 ? 260.0 : imageArray.count == 0 ? 0.0 : 130.0;
```

And also do height for text as:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

}

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    return 130 + cell.height.constant;
}
```

After done, it works well the same as the first picture, then I load images via `SDWebImage` framework, I create imageCollection of max 6 images in cell

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *imageViewCollection;

- (void)loadCellDataWithInfo: (SharedUserInfo *)info {

self.userInfo = info;
[self.avatarImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:info.profileImageUrlStr] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"penguinMe"]];

self.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.avatarImageView.frame.size.width/2.0;
self.name.text = info.fullName;
self.username.text = info.userName;
self.text.text = [info.postDic objectForKey:@"text"];
self.likeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [[info.postDic objectForKey:@"likesCount"]integerValue]];
self.commentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [[info.postDic objectForKey:@"commentsCount"]integerValue]];
self.elapsed.text = [info.postDic objectForKey:@"elapsed"];

NSArray *imageArray = [info.postDic objectForKey:@"images"];

[self loadImagesWithURLStr:imageArray];

self.height.constant = imageArray.count > 3 ? 260.0 : imageArray.count == 0 ? 0.0 : 130.0;

}

- (void)loadImagesWithURLStr: (NSArray *)urlStrArray {

switch (urlStrArray.count) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 4:
        for (int index = 0; index < urlStrArray.count; index++) {
            if (index >= 2) {
                [self.imageViewCollection[index + 1] sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStrArray[index]]];
            } else {
                [self.imageViewCollection[index] sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStrArray[index]]];
            }
        }
        break;

    default:
        for (int index = 0; index < urlStrArray.count; index++) {
            [self.imageViewCollection[index] sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStrArray[index]]];
        }
        break;
}  
}
```

And now I met problem, with some cell without images will load some images from somewhere else repeatedly, it seems only cell without any post images will met such a problem

[image: post sample 2]

[image]

Cell do have images works well, it depends on the imagesArray which contains different numbers of image URL String

At last all my reuse code and cell part code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

[cell loadCellDataWithInfo:self.followingArray[indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}

- (void)loadCellDataWithInfo: (SharedUserInfo *)info {

self.userInfo = info;
[self.avatarImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:info.profileImageUrlStr] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"penguinMe"]];

self.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.avatarImageView.frame.size.width/2.0;
self.name.text = info.fullName;
self.username.text = info.userName;
self.text.text = [info.postDic objectForKey:@"text"];
self.likeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [[info.postDic objectForKey:@"likesCount"]integerValue]];
self.commentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [[info.postDic objectForKey:@"commentsCount"]integerValue]];
self.elapsed.text = [info.postDic objectForKey:@"elapsed"];

NSArray *imageArray = [info.postDic objectForKey:@"images"];

[self loadImagesWithURLStr:imageArray];

self.height.constant = imageArray.count > 3 ? 260.0 : imageArray.count == 0 ? 0.0 : 130.0;

}
```

[image]

So above all, it's the problem with reuse imageViewCollection, any suggestions? Appreciated for that.

Comment: you should set the imageview to nil first before trying to reuse the cell. Basically put it before you try to download the images using sd_setImageWithURL

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two different cell `reuseIdentifier`. One identifier(say for example cell1) for cell having Images(say for example cell2) and one for cell do not having images. So you have to take two different `UITableViewCell`.

Code will be something like below :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(imagesArr.count == 0)
{
cellIdentifier = @"cell1";
}
else{
cellIdentifier = @"cell2";
}
 HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


 [cell loadCellDataWithInfo:self.followingArray[indexPath.row]];

  return cell;
}
```